# Loading external symbols in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openni

I am trying to debug OpenNI, so I downloaded the source, compiled, added the OpenNI project to my existing solution, included the new header files, linked to the newly compiled library, added OpenNI project references to my existing projects and added the .pdb locations to my VS symbols locations.

After all of this, I can still only hit the breakpoints in the header files. Whenever I add a breakpoint in a source, VS says symbols are not loaded. Anything I'm not doing/doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that the PDBs for the libraries aren't actually being loaded, or don't match the DLL you're loading.  Check the Output pane of VS10.  When it loads the DLL, does it say "Symbols loaded"?  If not, the PDB either wasn't found, or the wrong one was found.

Comment: I think that was it. Symbols were not loaded because my old DLLs location was still in the PATH variable. Can you post this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the PDBs for the libraries aren't actually being loaded, or don't match the DLL you're loading. Check the Output pane of VS10. When it loads the DLL, does it say "Symbols loaded"? If not, the PDB either wasn't found, or the wrong one was found.

(Originally a comment, posted as an answer at OP's request).

Comment: The symbols were in fact not loaded, because I forgot to modify my PATH variable. The old DLLs were still being loaded.